# Como colocar objetos em array vazio com React Hooks

Tags: javascript, react, react-hooks

Tenho o seguinte conjunto de dados:

```
const dados = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 50, 90];
const colors = [
  "#52DF9A",
  "#FFCE1C",
  "#3570BD",
  "#3570BD",
  "#00B894",
  "#FB6B32",
];
```

E tenho o seguinte estado:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([{}]);
```

Preciso percorrer os dados e colocar um dado com uma respectiva cor, para que o estado "dado" fique da seguinte maneira:

```js
data = [
  { valor: 5, color: "#52DF9A" },
  { valor: 10, color: "#FFCE1C" }, 
  // ...
];
```

Fiz da seguinte maneira com `useEffect`:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  dados.forEach((dado, i) => {
    setData((prev) => {
      return [...prev, { valor: dado, color: colors[i] }];
    });
  });
}, []);
```

Mas o problema é que, quando eu faço dessa forma, a primeira posição fica ocupada por um objeto vazio (`{}`), e eu preciso que os dados comecem na primeira posição. Como eu posso resolver isso?

Porque se eu fizer assim:

```js
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
```

Dá erro.

Comment: Em tese não era para `const [data, setData] = useState([])` dar erro. Poderia dizer em mais detalhes o que acontece?

Comment: Quando eu coloco apenas [ ] ele fala isso: Argument of type '(prev: never[]) => { valor: number; color: string; }[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<never[]>'.

Comment: Se você quiser entender porque isso ocorre, pode abrir uma **[outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)**. Só não se esqueça de criar um [mcve].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O problema é que você inicializa `data` como um *array* que já está com o primeiro elemento preenchido. No caso, por um objeto literal "vazio":

```
const [data, setData] = useState([{}]);
//                                ↑↑
//                Objeto "vazio" no primeiro elemento
```

Desse modo, quando a lógica que você colocou no `useEffect` for executada, o primeiro elemento será mantido no *array*, já que você *sempre* mantém o estado anterior no *array*:

> ```
> useEffect(() => {
>   dados.forEach((dado, i) => {
>     setData((prev) => {
>       return [...prev, { valor: dado, color: colors[i] }];
>     });
>   });
> }, []);
> ```

Note que o `...prev` está fazendo exatamente isso — mantendo o estado anterior.

---

Uma solução é inicializar o estado `data` como um *array* vazio:

```js
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
```

Se, por algum motivo, isso não for possível (o que deveria ser), você pode modificar a lógica do `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const newData = dados.map((valor, i) => ({
    valor,
    color: colors[i]
  }));

  setData(newData);
}, []);
```

Um exemplo do *array* que `newData` será:

```js
const dados = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 50, 90];
const colors = [
  "#52DF9A",
  "#FFCE1C",
  "#3570BD",
  "#3570BD",
  "#00B894",
  "#FB6B32",
];

const newData = dados.map((valor, i) => ({
  valor,
  color: colors[i]
}));

console.log(newData);
```